# How Can I select a value when multiple conditions are met in multiple columns?

Tags: sql

I was hoping someone can help me with a problem I am facing. I am looking to automate approval rules for invoices. I want to pull only invoices with a status of not_approved and match_auto. The invoice has these statuses on multiple rows.

| Invoice ID | Status Type | Status_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Match | Match_Auto |
| 12345 | Approval | Not_Approved |
| 54321 | Match | Not_Matched |
| 54321 | Approval | Not_Approved |

I want to do a check on both the Match and approval status type.

The return should be 12345 (both matched and not approved), but with my query I am getting 54321 as it is not_approved

Comment: Presumably 54321 shouldn't appear because of `not_matched` since `not_approved` is part of your requirement? Please add your existing query so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following should work:

```
SELECT [Invoice id]
  FROM [Whateverthetableiscalled]
 WHERE [Invoice id] IN (SELECT [Invoice id] 
                          FROM [Whateverthetableiscalled]    
                         WHERE [Status Type] ='Match' 
                           AND Status_Value='Match_Auto')
   AND [Invoice id] IN (SELECT [Invoice id] 
                          FROM [Whateverthetableiscalled] 
                         WHERE [Status Type]='Approval' 
                           AND Status_Value ='Not_Approved')
```